# Replace substring in stringbuilder, don't know location of substring

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, stringbuilder

Example: If the display name contains "Lambda (?)" then replace with "Lambda (&#955").

I have four various substrings that I'm trying to replace

Here's the part of my stringbuilder code:

```
sb.Append("<div><a href=\"" + item.URLAliasName + "\" >" + (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.DisplayName) ? "&nbsp;" : item.DisplayName) + "</a>"...
```

How do I replace "Lambda (?)" if contained inside item.DisplayName? It may be found anywhere in the display name.

Comment: Are you trying to replace the string: "Lambda (?)" with "Lambda(&#955)"?

Comment: `item.DisplayName.Replace("Lambda(?)", "Lambda(&#955)")`

Comment: Do be aware that building HTML like this opens you up to injection attacks (e.g. if `item.DisplayName` is `<script>alert('hacked!')</script>`.

Comment: Or do you actually have the character `λ ` in your string and you need it to be HTML encoded to `&#955;` or `&lambda;`?

Comment: @code4life you had the correct answer, very simple change. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would work?

```
item.DisplayName.Replace("Lambda (?)", "Lambda (&#955)");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `String.Replace` it takes in two strings as parameters, the value to replace and what to replace it with. It returns the resulting string.

For example: `String replacedString = String.Replace("Lambda(?)", "Lambda(&#955");`